# Python-Replacing Duplicatte information in a Text file

Tags: python, string, replace, split, xlsxwriter

I am currently working on a program that puts each word in a text file into xlsxwriter. It means I have to split the lines.

My problem is that I have to get rid of the duplicate information until first different element in a line. I can't come up with an idea regarding how to tackle it.

Text Example

```
Dave likes fresh green apples 
Dave likes fresh green peppers 
Dave hates fresh green apples 
Dave hates rotten green apples 
Jane likes fresh green apples
```

Desired Outcome in xlsxwriter

```
    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5 
R1 Dave likes fresh  green apples 
R2  X     X     X      X   peppers 
R3  X   hates fresh  green apples 
R4  X     X   rotten green apples 
R5 Jane likes fresh  green apples
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

challenge accepted.

How about something like this:

*test.txt*

```
Dave likes fresh green apples 
Dave likes fresh green peppers 
Dave hates fresh green apples 
Dave hates rotten green apples 
Jane likes fresh green apples
Dave likes fresh green watermelon
Jane likes fresh green peppers
```

here my first idea (making it function and documented from my original post)

```
def read_lines_with_duplicate_replace_v1(path,replace_char="X"):
    """Generator that read the lines in the file contained in path
       and for each line that start as some previous line replace each
       part that is similar with replace_char. Yield a list with the result"""
    #assume that each line has the same number of elements
    record=dict()
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            result  = line.split()
            temp = tuple(result)
            if temp[0] in record:
                key = result[0]
                result[0] = replace_char
                for i in range(1,len(result)):
                    if result[i] == record[key][i-1]:
                        result[i] = replace_char
                    else:
                        break
            record[temp[0]] = temp[1:]
            yield result
```

here is the second idea, remembering only the previous line

```
def read_lines_with_duplicate_replace_v2(path,replace_char="X"):
    """Generator that read the lines in the file contained in path
       and for each line that start as the previous line replace each
       part that is similar with replace_char. Yield a list with the result """
    #assume that each line has the same number of elements
    num_elem = 0
    previous_line = list()
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            result = line.split()
            if previous_line:
                for i in range(num_elem):
                    if result[i] == previous_line[i]:
                        result[i] = replace_char
                    else:
                        break
                previous_line[i:] = result[i:]
            else:
                previous_line.extend(result)
                num_elem = len(previous_line)
            yield result
```

output:

```
>>> for x in read_lines_with_duplicate_replace_v1("test.txt"):
        print(*x)


Dave likes fresh green apples
X X X X peppers
X hates fresh green apples
X X rotten green apples
Jane likes fresh green apples
X likes fresh green watermelon
X X X X peppers
>>>
>>>
>>> for x in read_lines_with_duplicate_replace_v2("test.txt"):
        print(*x)


Dave likes fresh green apples
X X X X peppers
X hates fresh green apples
X X rotten green apples
Jane likes fresh green apples
Dave likes fresh green watermelon
Jane likes fresh green peppers
>>>
```

Comment: You are beautiful person and I love you for it.

I had to made a few adjustments but it works nicely.  I had to change the line "for line in test.splitlines():". I appended the text file into a list first and use the list in thefor loop without "splitlines", otherwise I got an error. When using a list the "temp = line.split()" variable sees to be enough.

Comment: I use test.splitlines() because I do everything from the IDLE without reading a file, but that is equivalent to `test=open("test.txt").read()`, in your case you can do `with open("test.txt") as test:` `record=dict()` `for line in test:` and the rest is the same. The second time that I use `temp = line.split()` is to update the record with the last line as it is, in case that if it was change to X in the previous step don't save that. Now that I think about it, a dict is no needed either, well if you are interesting in the previous line only, in that case a list is enough

Comment: When I commented the record[temp[0]] = temp[1:] out the program didn't work as intended. So as it is right now the dict seems necessary

Comment: if you comment that line, of course its don't work because that is how it remember the previous stuff, when I say that the dict is no needed, I mean changing it for something else like a list

Comment: I make a update with the second version remembering only the previous line and some updates in the first version with reading a file instead and making it a generator function instead